# Python Variables and index

Tags: python, variables, indexing

I have been working on a program and I encountered a problem as I was programming.

---

this is my code:

```
dict=([{'geneA': [10, 20]}, {'geneB': [12, 45]}, {'geneC': [36, 50]}],
      [{'geneD': [45, 90]}, {'geneT': [100, 200]}],
      [{'geneF': [15, 25]}, {'geneX': [67, 200]}, {'GeneZ': [234, 384]}])
```

---

So I basically set up the dict equal to the data of chromosome1,2,and 3.
Is there any way in which I can display the names of these three strings in dict without having it as part of the dict index?

Comment: Thanks in advance! This is  not my full code of course, but it is the part I need help in.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: sorry i meant i want it to print the name of the three variables for each corresponding line

Comment: i just don't want it to be part of the index

Comment: Sorry, it's still very unclear. Do you just mean you want to print "Chromosome 1" for line 1, "Chromosome 2" for line 2, etc? If so that would seem to be a very simple for loop.

Comment: ya, just not part of the index

Comment: like i want it to say chromosome 1 next to line one, chromosome 2 next to line 2, so on so forth. i want it there for reference

Comment: sorry i recently learned python so i'm not the best at programming with it.

Comment: The problem is that a `dict` won't store items in the order you add them, so they won't come out in any guaranteed order. So if you want to keep those names assigned to those chromosomes, you either want an ordered dict or just to add those names to the dictionary directly.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is you're not declaring a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) but a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Try:

```
>> dict= {

    'chromosome1' : [{'geneA': [10, 20]}, {'geneB': [12, 45]}, {'geneC': [36, 50]}],
    'chromosome2' : [{'geneD': [45, 90]}, {'geneT': [100, 200]}],
    'chromosome3' : [{'geneF': [15, 25]}, {'geneX': [67, 200]}, {'GeneZ': [234, 384]}]
 }


>> print(dict['chromosome1'])
[{'geneA': [10, 20]}, {'geneB': [12, 45]}, {'geneC': [36, 50]}]
>> print(dict['chromosome2'])
[{'geneD': [45, 90]}, {'geneT': [100, 200]}]
>> print(dict['chromosome3'])
[{'geneF': [15, 25]}, {'geneX': [67, 200]}, {'GeneZ': [234, 384]}]
```

---

### POO approach

You can also try the POO approach. If you implement a couple of classes like below:

```
class Gene:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

class Chromosome:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
```

You will be able to write code like:

```
chromosome1 = Chromosome("chromosome1", [
    Gene('geneA', [10, 20]), 
    Gene('geneB', [12, 45]), 
    Gene('geneC', [36, 50])
])
```

and do thinks like:

```
print(chromosome1.name) # Print the chromosome name
>>> chromosome1
print(chromosome1[0].name) # The name of the first gene
>>> geneA
print(chromosome1[1].name) # The name of the second gene
>>> geneB
print(chromosome1[0][1])  # The second value of the first gene
20
```

You can also have a list of choromosomes (this is actually what you want):

```
lchrom = [chromosome1, ...]
print(lchrom[0][1]) # The second gene of the first choromosome in the list. (geneB)
print(lchrom[0][1][0]) # The first value second gene of the first choromosome in the list. (12)
```

Comment: never mind it messes with my index and doesn't allow me to do dict[0][1]